# Determining if a Java Iterable is ordered by contract

Tags: java, collections, contract, sorting

I am looking for a way to determine if a Collection (or maybe even any Iterable) is guaranteed to be ordered by its class contract.

I already know the Guava method : `Ordering.natural().isOrdered(myCollection)`
But this method is not relevant to my needs, because it checks if the values inside the collection are ordered. That's not what I need to determine, what I want to have is a `isSorted` method that will behave like this :

```
isSorted(new HashSet()) -> false
isSorted(new ArrayList()) -> true
```

etc...

What I am looking at would be typically implemented by checking the class of the collection, and comparing it to some kind of reference table of the collections which contract states that they are ordered, and only return true for these ones.

Do you know if something like this already exists in some library ?

Comment: `ArrayList` is ordered, not sorted.

Comment: How would this class (or method) know if it was ordered without looking at either 1. The JavaDoc for that class 2. The source code of that class (and analyzing it) or 3. Already having a map of the values stored as a member (which wouldn't work too well with my newly defined anonymous `Collection`)?

Comment: Yes, what I really mean is "is this Collection from a class that is ordered by contract ?"

If I was to implement such a method, I would definitely gather a table of "trusted" classes that are ordered by contract, and return true only for those classes (and of course, specify the exact methods that are included in the reference table as being the contract of this "isOrdered" method)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to determine if a collection is defined to be sorted.

```
collection instanceof SortedSet
```

Comment: indeed, that's the way that I would implement such a method I'm looking for, but I was wondering if it had been already done, with a comprehensive list of the types to check against.

Answer (score 0):

There are three interfaces for ordered collections: List, SortedSet and SortedMap. You can check if your class is implementing one of them.

Comment: But there are also classes that implement Collection without implementing either of these three interfaces, and that are ordered by contract. `LinkedHashSet` for example.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't exist in any library, and for good reason.

That library would have to know all the collection types that are flying around.  If you're using Apache Commons Collections, it'd have to know about all of those.  If you're using Guava, it'd have to know about all of those.  If someone comes along and introduces a new collection type, you're now going to reject that type, even if it's ordered.

It doesn't make sense to provide that method in a library that can't know what other libraries you might have with whatever other collection types might be out there.

In an end application, it might make sense to implement it, with the heuristic techniques you've already been describing.

It might help if we knew what you were actually trying to do with this method.